# How to position an element as if it were relative but have properties as if it were absolute?

Tags: html, css

Say I were to make a div. I want to position it relatively, say 100 pixels to the right of where it normally would be. However, I want all other divs to ignore it as if it were positioned absolute. How would I do this?

Comment: Can you provide an example? Also what code do you have currently?

Comment: Is this question solved? There's an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Have 2 elements one in another. First one simple `position: absolute;` while inner has `position: relative; right: 100px`. Put any content that is needed inside `.inner`

```css
body {
    counter-reset: foo-counter;
}

div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  text-align: center;
}

div:not(.pop):before {
  counter-increment: foo-counter;
  content: "# " counter(foo-counter);
}

.pop {
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(120, 0, 0, .7);
}

.pop:before {
  counter-increment: foo-counter;
  content: "# " counter(foo-counter);
}

.inner {
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 40, 0, .2);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div class="pop"><div class="inner"></div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```